# hapi server : when i request with POST method, hapi server responding with null, but working fine in localhost

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, joi, hapi

using **hapi** server -v = 16.7
joi -v = 10.6
deployed in aws ec2, nginx reverse proxy

### Server Code in server.js:

```
'use strict';

//let newrelic = require('newrelic');
let Hapi = require('hapi');
let Routes = require('./Routes');
let Plugins = require('./Plugins');
let Bootstrap = require('./Utils/BootStrap');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const Pack = require('./package');
const Config = require('./Config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


const server = new Hapi.Server();



server.connection({
    port: Config.dbConfig.config.PORT,
    routes: {cors: true}
});

let mongoOpts = {
    reconnectTries: 60,
    reconnectInterval: 2000,
    useMongoClient:true
};
mongoose.connect(Config.dbConfig.config.dbURI,mongoOpts, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("DB Error: ", err);
        process.exit(1);
    } else {
        console.log('MongoDB Connected');
        
    }
});

server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    {
        'register': HapiSwagger,
        'options': {
            info: {
                'title': Config.dbConfig.config.SWAGGERNAME,
                'version': Pack.version,
                description: '',
            },
           
            //documentationPath: '/',
            tags:[
                {
                    name: 'v2.1.0',
                    description: 'API'
                }
            ],
            grouping: 'tags',            
        },
    }], (err) => {
    server.start((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Server err----------->", err);
        } else {
            console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
        }
    });
});


server.on('response', (request) => {console.log('response===>>>:');
    if(request.url.path.startsWith('/panel')){
    }
    else {//console.log('HEADERS===========>:',request.headers);
        /* console for checking the params in the request*/
        console.log(request.info.remoteAddress + ': ' + request.method.toUpperCase() +
            ' ' + request.url.path + ' --> ' + request.response.statusCode);
        console.log('Request payload:', request.payload);
    }
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});



server.register(Plugins, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        server.error('Error while loading plugins : ' + err)
    } else {
        server.log('info', 'Plugins Loaded')
    }
});

server.register(Inert, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    server.route(Routes);
});

server.route([
  

    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',                      /* show error page */
        handler: function (req, res) {
            res.file('./error.html')
        }
    },

    {
        path: "/panel/{path*}",
        method: "GET",
        handler: {                              /* open admin panel index from panel path*/
            directory: {
                path: ['./_admin'],
                listing: false,
                index: ['index.html']
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

This is deployed in AWS-EC2, with Nginx reverse proxy.When we hit POST request with payload, working fine in localhost and saves data to MongoDB. But when we hit same POST method from another domain against ec2 deployed server,  the below error is showing in pm2 logs. It seems its responding with null before running the controller.

### Error in pm2 logs, when we hit POST method:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of null
at /var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/server.js:123:65
at Object.internals.handler (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:283:33)
at invoke (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:255:23)
at each (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:259:13)
at Object.exports.parallel (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:70:13)
at Object.internals.emit (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:276:18)
at module.exports.internals.Server.internals.Podium._emit (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:156:15)
at each (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:197:47)
at Object.exports.parallel (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:70:13)
at relay (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:198:15)
at Object.internals.emit (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:202:16)
at internals.emitEmitter (/var/www/html/vhosts/custom_BE_ecommerce/api/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:303:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:79:21)
```

Need help on this issue.

Comment: The error appears to be coming from the line where you have `request.response.statusCode`, inside of the `response` event handler. The [documentation for the `response` event](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#-response-event) says: "The 'response' event type is emitted after the response is sent back to the client (or when the client connection closed and no response sent, in which case `request.response` is `null`)". Sounds like the client connection is closing prematurely, which may indicate something is wrong in the NGINX configuration. I suggest checking the NGINX logs.

Comment: @SethHolladay I tried from the ec2 server itself with `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8000/test'` , even though no response from the application.